# Simplest way to index within a dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors `x` and `y` that have equal `shape` in the first `k` dimensions. The second tensor contains indices to retrieve values from the first along to the last dimension. For a `rank` of 3, then the output `z` should be such that `z[i_1, i_2,...,i_k, j] = x[i_1, i_2,...,i_k, y[i_1, i_2, ...,i_k, j]]`.

I currently have a method that requires reshaping the `x` and `y`, appending row indices of `y`, using `gather_nd` and finally returning to the original shape. Is there is a more elegant method? Is there a way to get the tensor of indices (like `np.indices`), preferably that does not require knowledge of the rank or shape beyond that they satisfy the above condition?

Answer (score 3):

Found it! `tf.batch_gather` and `tf.batch_scatter`.